# Disable touch event to specified screen on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg, xinput

I've configured two independent screens on Ubuntu 18.04 according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54077/how-do-i-configure-a-second-monitor-as-an-independent-xscreen-with-unity).
Now I want to confine touch input event on one of screen. `xinput map-to-output 10 DP-1` doesn't work!

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ILITEK ILITEK-TP                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logi TKL Mechanical Keyboard Consumer Control    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ILITEK ILITEK-TP Mouse                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logi TKL Mechanical Keyboard     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logi TKL Mechanical Keyboard     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logi TKL Mechanical Keyboard Consumer Control    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell AIO WMI hotkeys                      id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The following command shows the screen0:

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+  74.97
```

For screen 1:
xrandr --screen 1
Screen 1: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    23.98

How can I achieve the goal? Thanks!